# How to add FBSDKLoginButton default image to a custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, uibutton

I want to integrate Parse with Facebook. For that I need to call PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions method anywhere I want. In the parse guide to integrate them it tells to call this method and the Parse and Facebook accounts will be linked, nothing more . I’m calling it when a UIButton instance is touched up inside and everything works fine, but I’d like to know how to add the FBSDKLoginButton (the simple behaviour button without linking users,just authenticating them to Facebook) default image to my custom button.

Comment: you want to login to your app (which uses Parse), using Facebook only. So how do you plan to login with parse?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered the question:
how to login to parse (with creating PFUser to use all comfortable Parse stuff) , using FBSDKLoginbutton design and great functionality.
Hope this is the question you asked.
My solution:
Use your button as FBSDKLoginButton (change class of a button in identity inspector), 
add FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate to your class

```
        @IBOutlet var fbLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

class ViewController: UIViewController , FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate  {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.fbLoginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email", "user_friends" ]
    self.fbLoginButton.delegate = self
}
```

Xcode will bark at you because you need to clear out for him what should it do, when it logged in and logged out:

```
      //login to Facebook  
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
    if let token = result.token{

//login to Parse with token
        PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithAccessToken(token, block: { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                //process error
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            else
            {
                //here you have your PFUser
            }
})
}
}
```

Don't forget Log out instructions for Delegate:

```
        func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    PFUser.logOutInBackground()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're looking at creating your own version of `FBSDKLoginButton` that can work with the Parse `PFFacebookUtils`.

I recently had the same necessity and I used the following approach:

1. Create a UIButton - `customUIButton`
2. Create a FBSDKLoginButton - `fbSDKLoginButton`
3. Set `fbSDKLoginButton.userInteractionEnabled = false`
4. Add `fbSDKLoginButton` as subview of `customUIButton`
5. Add the actions you need to `customUIButton` to handle the login yourself via Parse - the FBSDKLoginButton will be "transparent" to user touches but will keep getting automatically updated when it receives login/logout notifications from the SDK.

Here's my sample code in Swift:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Parse

class CustomFBLoginButton: UIButton
{
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        let fbSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        fbSDKLoginButton.userInteractionEnabled = false//so it won't respond to touches
        self.addSubview(fbSDKLoginButton)
        self.frame = fbSDKLoginButton.frame//FBSDKLoginButton gets automatically the right frame - so let's adjust its superview to have exactly the same frame
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let customFBLoginButton = CustomFBLoginButton()
        customFBLoginButton.addTarget(self, action: "customButtonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(customFBLoginButton)
    }

    func customButtonTapped(button: CustomFBLoginButton)
    {
        //handle login/logout via the Parse SDK
        if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
            PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock({ (_) -> Void in
                println("logged out")//the button will now refresh although I noticed a small delay 1/2 seconds
            })
        }
        else {
            PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(nil)//set the permissions you need
        }
    }
}
```